# Updating MediaBrowserService to MediaBrowserServiceCompat removes 'browse' function

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-wear-notification

I've been busy updating the [universal Android Mediaplayer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) to use the Compat libraries to get it working on Android versions lower than lollipop.

This was a process of replacing most classes by the compat variants of them. You can see the commit with all my changes [here](https://github.com/Marc1510/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/commit/3626d74a3013f17d779940a2235e9130b36ec637).

The thing I don't like right now is that the 'browse' function has dissapeard on the Wear device. This function can be seen in the images below.

[image] [image]

I just made screenshots of this function with the latest version of the Universal Music Player. When I updated the most classes to their compat variants this function dissapeard.

I don't know if I forgot to update something, if the function should be activated somehow or any other reason why it doesn't work.

Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** As of [Android Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html), `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` is public and fully compatible with Android Auto and Android Wear (exactly the same as `MediaBrowserService`). A full description of what `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` can do is found in [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/mediabrowserservicecompat-and-the-modern-media-playback-app-7959a5196d90).

*Previous Answer*: `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` as of version 23.1.1 is not yet compatible with things that require a framework `MediaBrowserService` (such as Android Wear and Android Auto) - that is coming in a future release.

Comment: You'll note that `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` actually has a `@hide` annotation on it if you look at the source, hence why it is not in the documentation nor mentioned in the [release notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: Note, the answer has changed! Support Library 23.2 makes `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` official!

Comment: MediaBrowserService connect method gives null pointer exception? Any idea? spent almost half day behind this 

`boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
android.os.Binder.queryLocalInterface(Binder.java:254)
 android.service.media.IMediaBrowserService$Stub.asInterface(IMediaBrowserService.java:31)`

Comment: @sam_k 0 that sounds like a different question.